# Using Explorer as a file prompt in Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, csv, scripting

I am using the CSV library in ruby to deal with large CSV files. I would like to eventually make an executable that will allow the user to select the CSV file in windows explorer instead of typing in the complete filepath. Can anyone help me with this?

```
#explorer prompt for file or filename
CSV.foreach(returned_pathname) do |row|
  #processing
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you have to use one of GUI libraries. [Here](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/gui_frameworks) you can choose one.

And you also need some of [these](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/packaging_to_executables.html) to make your app an executable.

Answer (score 0):

I uses the [shoes](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4) library for my simple Ruby GUI needs.

Then you could do something like this, of course you will need to add more code to this, but it should get you started.

```
Shoes.app :width => 512, :height => 384, :title => 'My App' do
  # Browse for file button
  stack(left: 35, top: 90) do
    @push = button 'Browse for file'
    note = para 'Please select an Excel file', left: 35
    @push.click do
      filename = ask_open_file
      note.replace filename.to_s
    end
  end
end
```